# Remix IDE Error: Different number of arguments in return statement than in returns declaration

Tags: remix

I am trying to compile the following contract on Remix.

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract financialContracts3{

address issuer;
constructor() public{
   issuer = msg.sender;
}
modifier ifIssuer(){
   if(issuer != msg.sender){
      revert();
   }else {
        _;//underscore
   }
}
function receiveFunds( )public payable{

}
function getValue() public constant {
   return issuer.balance;
}
}
```

I am getting following error message:

> > browser/financialContract3.sol:20:4: TypeError: Different number of
> >     arguments in return statement than in returns declaration.    return
> >     issuer.balance;
>
> ^-------------------^

Some body please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: I am getting following warning now:
browser/financialContract3.sol:20:11: Warning: Using contract member "balance" inherited from the address type is deprecated. Convert the contract to "address" type to access the member, for example use "address(contract).balance" instead.
   return this.balance;
          ^----------^

Comment: I tried the following  and it worked: function getValue() public view returns(uint) {
  address myAddress = this;
return myAddress.balance;
}
as provided a solution at another place.

Answer (score 1):

In Solidity, you must be explicit about the variables that you return from a function. So here would be a corrected version of your code:

```
function getValue() public view returns(uint){
   return this.balance;
}
```